# Ubuntu16.04 boot to black screen hp pavilion

Tags: boot, screen, hp, hp-pavilion

After installing Ubuntu on my HP pavilion DV6 through CD version 16.04 and erasing Windows,
computer turns to black screen everytime I boot.
I have done some research and the fn+F3 doesn't seem to work (increasing brightness) my computer is quite old and the F10 key for example doesn't work...
The only option I have now is to
Press escape while boot
Press E to change parameters
Erase "quiet splash" either for Nothing or for "acpi_backlight=vendor" .

"nomodeset" also allows me to start the computer and use it normally.
What I would like now is to save these changes so I could start the computer normally with no manipulation.

The problem is I can't seem to find a way to save these changes and make them default.
Thank you for your time and attention !

Michael

Answer (score 1):

The `nomodeset` can be set as a default, by editing the grub configuration files:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Find the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and add nomodeset to the list of parameters.  Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file, and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit.

Follow this with `sudo update-grub`